# Fix header when scrolling with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]I have a large bootstrap table, when i try to fix the header the table is distorted, but header is fixed. As a result some rows get stacked over that make the table become distorted. This is my fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/1veu9gz3/

How can fix this ?

css

```
    .table-fixed tbody {
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 100%;
    }
    .table-fixed thead,
    .table-fixed tbody,
    .table-fixed tr,
    .table-fixed td,
    .table-fixed th {
    display: block;
    }
    .table-fixed tr:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    clear: both;
    }
    .table-fixed tbody td,
    .table-fixed thead > tr > th {
    float: left;
    }
```

html

```
    <table class="table table-bordered table-fixed" >
     <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Fecha de la consulta</th>
    <th>Semana de amenorrea</th>
    <th>Peso (lb)</th>
    <th>Tension Arterial Max.Min. (mm Hg)</th>
    <th>Alt. Ulterina/Present Pubis.FondoCef/Pelv.Tr</th>
    <th>F.C.F.(lat./min./Mov.Fetal)</th>
    <th>Edema / Varices</th>
    <th>Otros</th>
    <th>Evolucion</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text"  size="10"  /></td>
    <td><input type="text"  size="10"  /></td>
    <td><input type="text"  size="10"  /></td>
    <td><div class="input-group" ><input style="width:50px" class="form-control reduce-height" type="text"   /> <span class="input-group-addon reduce-height" >-</span> <input  type="text" class="form-control reduce-height" style="width:50px" /></div></td>
    <td><div class="input-group" > <input style="width:50px" class="form-control reduce-height" type="text"   /> <span class="input-group-addon reduce-height" >-</span> <input  type="text" class="form-control reduce-height" style="width:50px" /><span class="input-group-addon reduce-height" >-</span><input  type="text" class="form-control reduce-height" style="width:50px" /></div></td>
    <td><div class="input-group" ><input style="width:50px" class="form-control reduce-height" type="text"   /> <span class="input-group-addon reduce-height" >-</span> <input  type="text" class="form-control reduce-height" style="width:50px" /></div></td>
    <td><div class="input-group" ><input style="width:50px" class="form-control reduce-height" type="text"   /> <span class="input-group-addon reduce-height" >-</span> <input  type="text" class="form-control reduce-height" style="width:50px" /></div></td>
    <td><textarea style="width:150px" class="form-control" cols="20"></textarea></td>
    <td><textarea style="width:150px" class="form-control" cols="20"></textarea></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
     .
     .
     .
     </table>
```

Comment: which part of the code is distorting the table, you mention when u fix the header, with what ?

Comment: .table-fixed tbody {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  }

Comment: you have set a height of 200px, that will shrink the table!

Comment: before i posted i tried to increase the height still no result.

Comment: sorry i dont understand what your asking for, i took it out and it renders the whole table ?

Comment: See my update , I just added the image of the result. The header is fixed but table is distorted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162533/discussion-between-diasline-and-saj).